# Change name of Placemark in .kml using NetworkLink & NetworkLinkControl all inside a .kmz

Tags: kml, google-earth, kmz

I am having trouble renaming a Placemark within a KML using NetworkLink and NetworkLinkControl in Google Earth.
The Placemark and NetworkLink are in the same KML and NetworkLinkControl in another (both inside a KMZ).

The contents of my `test.kmz`:

```
doc.kml
nltest.kml
```

The contents of my `doc.kml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns='http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1'>
<Document>
<name>top level document</name>
<Folder id="topFolder">
<Placemark id="pm123">
<name>some silly thing</name>
<Point>
<coordinates>-95.44,40.42,0</coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
<NetworkLink>
<name>changename</name>
<visibility>0</visibility>
<Link>
<href>nltest.kml</href>
</Link>
</NetworkLink>
</Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

The contents of my `nltest.kml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<NetworkLinkControl>
<Update>
<targetHref>doc.kml</targetHref>
<Change>
<Placemark targetId="pm123">
<name>something other</name>
</Placemark>
</Change>
</Update>
</NetworkLinkControl>
</kml>
```

Expected behavior: When NetworkLink "changename" is toggled from off to on, Placemark "some silly thing" name changes to "something other".

Tested behavior: Nothing happens when NetworkLink "changename" is toggled from off to on.

Tried removing visibility from NetworkLink. Did not work.